# What would the cubic formula be if roots never existed?

Tags: polynomials, roots, continued-fractions, roots-of-cubics

$$ax^{2}+bx+c=0$$
$$x=-\frac{b}{a}+\frac{1}{\frac{b}{c}+\frac{1}{-\frac{b}{a}+\frac{1}{\frac{b}{c}+\frac{1}{...}}}}$$
$$ax^{3}+bx^{2}+cx+d=0$$
$$x=?$$
I know it can't recur like the quadratic continued fraction. Must be arithmetic operations. Got ideas?

Comment: What is exactly the questions here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compare five ways of solving cubic equation by iterations (nested expressions)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1669163/compare-five-ways-of-solving-cubic-equation-by-iterations-nested-expressions). See also [Finding a substitution that eliminates the squared term from a cubic equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2424827/finding-a-substitution-that-eliminates-the-squared-term-from-a-cubic-equation) for how to reduce it to a depressed cubic in the first place.

Comment: So far as I know, apart from the quadratic case, there _is_ no simple description of continued-fraction expansions of ... anything. But/and, also, your question title, etc. is misleading...

Comment: Second question: since we are using infinitely many operations, could these types of formulas actually solve the quintic or higher degree polynomials? 1 of the restrictions of the unsolvability of the quintic (Ruffini-Abel theorem) is we only use finitely many operations, but here we use infinitely many.

Comment: @BabyHeartyBear Any of the [numerical methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithms#Roots_of_polynomials) for finding polynomial roots with arbitrary precision is iterative at core, though the recurrence relations become complicated.